# Div not showing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some trouble displaying a div on click using JQuery. All the code looks correct to me. On my website I have a searchbar that I am trying to add search suggestions to. But by default I would like it to be hidden. Only if the user selects "Show Suggestions", then it will appear. The form action being empty is irrelevent. It does not work even if I remove the form all together. I am not getting any errors. I have been trying to fix this problem for over an hour, I appreciate any help with this.

HTML

```
<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" />
    <input type="submit"  value="Search" /><button id="hint"/>Show Suggestions </button>
</form>

<div id="searchhint" style="display:none; border:1px solid red; width:300px;" > Suggestions:<span id="txtHint"></span></font></div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hint").click(function(){
    $("#searchhint").show();
  });
});
```

Comment: try debugging or adding console.log to tell whether the problem is with the event (is `show` getting called in the first place?) or with the body of the event handler (`show` gets called but doesn't work?)

Comment: Are you sure jquery is loaded?

Comment: Your code works when extracted: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/rdBsk/ (note that I added `return false` to prevent the form from submitting. Check your console for other errors.

Comment: Fix all your HTML, then test again.

Comment: I fixed everything mentioned in this post, and still no luck:/ I appreciate all the help though.

Comment: Darnit! I had some javascript code running on my page so I unconciously assumed jquery should work, though I am aware it MUST be loaded first. My JQuery was not loaded, all is working well now. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @MHZ either you delete your question, or you add your own answer in a few days and accept it then :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to load JQuery. I had JavaScript running on my page so I presumed JQuery should work as well, though I am aware that it MUST be loaded first in order for it to work. So to all of the people with a similar problem, first check if you loaded JQuery.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is malformed, you close a "font" tag that you never open within that #searchhint div. The Font tag is depreciated anyway, so you should avoid using it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this still did not fix my problem.

Comment: Even though the HTML is malformed, as this doesn't answer the question, this should be a comment.

Comment: When I fixed the markup in my sample, it fixed the functionality - hence my response is an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to prevent the default behaviour. use [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hint").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    $("#searchhint").show();
  });
});
```

Sample  : http://jsfiddle.net/Nbq9Y/3/

This should work assuming you have the valid HTML markup and no other script errors in the page.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. There is no default behavior that needs to be cancelled for a button element, nor would any default behavior prevent this from being fired. If this were an <a> element, then maybe...

Comment: @Arbiter: If the button is inside a form, browsers will do a form submit. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp .Ideally he should use input type="button"/> in this kind of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your button tag... you've closed it out before "Show Suggestions"

Comment: It still works. Browsers a nice to stupid mistakes nowadays :) See http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/rdBsk/

Comment: I put it into a fiddle, too... it bailed on me in Chrome... however, fixing up the malformed HTML made it work just fine... also... i had to add an action to the form because it was reloading the fiddle when I pushed the button... which I found very weird.